# Accessing and transfer sim contacts to Droid 2 global phone

Tags: contacts, motorola-droid-2

I have a Droid 2 Global and I can't seem to access the contacts on my sim card. How do I access them and transfer them to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app such as [SIM contacts manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ice.andrea.contactmanager&hl=en) or [SIM Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.needom.simcontacts&hl=en) to manage your contact on your SIM card, including accessing and transferring them to the phone.

If you have Android 4.0+, you can do this straight from your contacts app.
`Open Contacts > Menu > Import/export > Import from SIM card`